# Solution check: integral calculation using transformations

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Could somebody check my solution to the following problem?

Calculate $\iint_Ey\cos(y^2-4-x)dxdy$ if $E \in ]-\infty,0]\times [0,+\infty[$ enclosed by $x=-2, y=0, y^2-4=x$.

Using $u=y^2-3,\quad v=y^2-4-x$

I have $\sin(2)$ as a solution?

(Is there a way to check these problems using Wolfram Alpha?)

Comment: I have $\sin^21$ as solution, but it's not clear to me how you solved this.

Did you draw the area and find the integration limits? What were they? There is no wolframalpha-way to check if you don't have the limits...

Comment: thnx, i've got the following:
$v-1\leq u\leq v+1$ and $-2\leq v \leq 0$

I'm not really sure if the limit of $v$ is right...
I've search them using the following method: $-2\leq x \leq 0$ and $0\leq y \leq \sqrt{x+4}$ and then substituting the values for $x$ and $y$...

PS: i've got $x=u-v-1 \quad y=\sqrt{u+3}$

Comment: $x$ and $y$ information added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a problem which you have to solve by a multivariable substitution?  Because in fact it's not too hard in $(x,y)$ coordinates, if that's allowed.  Start with
$$I=\int_0^{\sqrt2}\int_{y^2-4}^{-2} y\cos(y^2-4-x)\,dx\,dy\ ,$$
then the integral with respect to $x$ is easy.  After substituting the limits of integration you end up with
$$\int_0^{\sqrt2} -y\sin(y^2-2)\,dy$$
which can be done with a standard substitution.  My answer was $\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos2)$, and using a double angle formula simplifies this to $\sin^21$.

See if you can fill in the details I have omitted.

Comment: Okay, I've made some rather silly calculation errors. Thanks!